# Change run user from nt authority\system to AD user - Apache on Windows

Tags: php, apache

I check run user as code below.

```
<?php 
echo(exec('whoami'));
?>
```

Output, run user is nt authority\system as picture below.

[image]

I can't find the user in `Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf` as picture below.

[image: httpd.conf]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

1. Open Services.

2. Right click on Apache2.2.

3. Click Properties.

4. Click Log On tab.

5. Set user.
[image: Services]

Comment: Oh my god! Please receive a million points! I would have never found this!!!!